# UIPageViewController sharing variable among children

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a MasterViewController that is a UIPageViewController that has four view controllers. The tasks array contain Task objects. This tasks array should only have one instance and should be shared among the children so any changes made are updated in the corresponding view controller (I will notify the view controllers using NotificationCenter)

```
class MasterViewController: UIPageViewController {

let vcs = [TodayListViewController(), PlannerViewController(), ReviewListViewController(), AddViewController()]

static var tasks = [
    Task(id: "1", title: "Mock up onboarding", completed: true, priority: 0),
    Task(id: "2", title: "Connect to Firebase", completed: false, priority: 1),
    Task(id: "3", title: "Code review", completed: false, priority: 0),
    Task(id: "4", title: "Add beta testers to TestFlight", completed: false, priority: 1)
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Gray")
    dataSource = self
    setViewControllers([vcs[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false)
}
```

}

**My current solution**

I have made the array static so it can be accessed in the child view controllers by just typing

```
MasterViewController.tasks
MasterViewController.tasks.append(task) // When adding a new task in the AddViewController
```

Is this an acceptable approach?

**The Singleton solution**

I have tried making a singleton and storing the array there and it does work however I do not like the idea of using a singleton design pattern due to the controversy that surrounds it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `tasks` in a class, as an instance property. Create, and keep a reference to, an instance of that wrapper class in the page view controller. Whenever the page view controller creates a child, use dependency injection: hand the child a reference to the wrapper instance.

Comment: Do you know where I can find conventions and documentation on creating wrapper classes?

Comment: It's a class because that's a reference type, so you can share the array. You can give it whatever amount of public api you like, if you're not comfortable with everyone accessing the array directly. Personally I'd make the array private and provide access thru public methods.

Comment: This is a good solution. Lastly, what would you call this class? e.g. DataManager which contains all my variables that I want my child controllers to have a reference too?